# What's the point of ASP.net AJAX in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So ASP.net MVC by default ships with both JQuery and ASP.net Ajax. While the use cases of JQuery are obvious and plenty, I just wonder what the point of ASP.net Ajax is? If I just have my Controller Actions return JSON, I don't need it? Also, any "old" ASP.net controls only work if you use the Webforms view Engine (I think I want to use another one, but that's not the point).

What has ASP.net Ajax to offer in an MVC Environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET AJAX is a bit different from JQuery it is sort of a large library of stuff and allows you to use similarly named APIs as you would in typical .NET programming. You have a bit more string functions and so forth. That being said, I typically bypass ASP.NET AJAX altogether and find most of what I need in JQuery and other smaller libraries. ASP.NET AJAX is a bit top heavy for my tastes but it does have its uses.

Answer (score 5):

Familiarity for those who are used to using the ASP.NET AJAX.